# Command not found when opening terminal, possible conda issue?

Tags: macos, terminal, conda

for some reason whenever I open my terminal it immediately prints the following (after the "last login" line of course):

```
(eval):116: command not found: dirname
(eval):116: command not found: dirname
__add_sys_prefix_to_path:6: command not found: dirname
__add_sys_prefix_to_path:7: command not found: dirname
```

It appears that terminal still works fine, but I can't seem to figure out what the cause of these errors could be. The only thing I've "changed" in my terminal last time I used it was setting up a conda environment and installing some new packages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tampered with the PATH variable and your current PATH cannot figure out where your common utilities are located.

try:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Fix the last entry you made in your bash_profile or zshrc file before you started encountering the error.