# (eval):66: command not found: dirname

Tags: terminal, command, iterm, dirname

After i set anaconda there is an error

Iterm error : `(eval):66: command not found: dirname`

##################################
`which python`
-> `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`

`which dirname`
-> `/usr/bin/dirname`

this is my .zshrc file.
`export CONDA_AUTO_ACTIVATE_BASE=false export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}`

but it still does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found when opening terminal, possible conda issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873005/command-not-found-when-opening-terminal-possible-conda-issue)

Answer (score -1):

Try PATH="$PATH/{directory name}"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry I tried to write `export PATH="$PATH/{directory name}"`in zshrc file,
but the error messages still appear