# Why did this permanently mess up my terminal from being able to run commands?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, path, zsh

Hi I broke my terminal environment or something because I have no idea how any of this stuff works and I was trying to install tartube by following the installation instructions for it on Github.
So mindlessly copy/pasting the commands in the guide into terminal... then after I ran these commands for troubleshooting the install:

```
echo "export PATH="python3 -m site --user-base/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.zprofile

source ~/.zprofile
```

Now this is what my terminal looks like after opening it and trying to run some basic commands:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 11 20:10:15 on ttys000
/Users/censoringmyfullname/.zprofile:export:6: not valid in this context: -m
/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:104: command not found: mkdir
censoringmyfullname@supername-mbp ~ % zsh
zsh: command not found: zsh
censoringmyfullname@supername-mbp ~ % brew
zsh: command not found: brew
censoringmyfullname@supername-mbp ~ % sudo
zsh: command not found: sudo
censoringmyfullname@supername-mbp ~ % 
censoringmyfullname@supername-mbp ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/censoringmyfullname/.pyenv/bin:python3
```

So now my terminal says weird stuff when I open it and none of the commands work. I've tried a bunch of internet guides to reset zsh shells, whatever that is, by some variation of PATH = "gibb:/erish/gobblygook" and nothing works.

Any advice or especially commands that magically fix this with no explanation would be wholly appreciated by grug, so that I can return to world of concepts I understand, thank you !!!! (I will venmo and/or send good vibes - thank you)

I read this
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050
and this
https://youngstone89.medium.com/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c
and also this
[Command not found when opening terminal, possible conda issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873005/command-not-found-when-opening-terminal-possible-conda-issue)

And none helped

Comment: I’d delete your zprofile from finder. Looks like you didn’t quote the path ok

Comment: Doing such an `echo` to blindly write something into your .profile is pretty brave, as you don't have any feedback of what's going on. There is a wonderful kind of tools called "text editors", and we use them to edit text files. In the future, use such programs to edit your files, instead of shooting at them from the command line. Now that you have ruined the file, fix it - but using a **text editor** instead of indivdual commands, lest you would risk ruining it even more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoting in that command is *completely* messed up, so the first thing to do is remove the line it added from your ~/.zprofile file. From the error message, that appears to be line #6 in the file (and probably the last line, unless something else has been added after it). The line will look something like this:

```
export PATH=python3 -m site --user-base/bin:/lots/more/stuff/here
```

You can do this with a command-line editor if you're comfortable with one, but you'll need to specify the full path to the editor, like `/usr/bin/nano ~/.profile` or `/usr/bin/vi ~/.profile`. If you prefer to use a GUI editor, I recommend [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html) for things like this. Even in free/unpaid mode, it can edit hidden files (like .zprofile), and it doesn't mess things up by adding formatting, smart quotes, etc like many editors do.

Once you've removed that, open a new Terminal window and make sure things are working normally, then run this to add the *correct* line to your ~/.zprofile. I think this'll do the right thing:

```
echo 'export PATH="'"$(python3 -m site --user-base)"'/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Many many thanks brother, I will try this tomorrow, good vibes sent

Comment: @WindowBreaker Be sure to report back if it works (actually, you shouldn't accept this as the "correct" answer until/unless it works). Assuming it does, you should also submit it as a correction to the guide you got the messed-up command from.